# Is there experimental evidence of time order inversion for spacelike events?

Tags: special-relativity, experimental-physics, causality

The title sums up the question. Given two events separated by a spacelike interval, say one takes place after the other in an inertial frame, then by a suitable boost we may invert the time order of both events.(This of course is not possible for timelike separated events) My question is hence: is there is any direct experimental evidence of this? And if not direct, then somewhat indirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Relativity of simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity) is a logical consequence of c's invariance. Time order reverseals have not been tested directly *as far as I know*, but since the invariance of c from which the relativity follows has been tested in a lot of [experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_special_relativity) I would say that the thought experiments regarding this issue are solid.