# Is the intuition of “absolute simultaneity” necessarily wrong?

Tags: experimental-physics, soft-question, time, relativity

I read about Einstein’s theories of relativity with all the interesting stuff like time dilation, mass increase and whatnot. And also about the relativity or conventionality of simultaneity. The latter I found the most interesting.  I now know that relative simultaneity is at the least assumed to be true. And that the experimentally well verified theories of relativity have relativity of simultaneity as an axiom.

**But was it proven that there is no absolute simultaneity ? Is there any practical experiment to distinguish between relative and absolute simultaneity ? Has it been done already ?**

My intuition tells me that that proving the truth of relative simultaneity compared to absolute simultaneity is impossible, except if time-travel into the past was possible. However my intuition also tells me that the absence of absolute simultaneity is an inconsistent idea, which would contradict the very theories of relativity.

So I’m very curious what answer the people of physics, who should know this stuff better than me, can provide to my question.

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165507/is-there-experimental-evidence-of-time-order-inversion-for-spacelike-events/165521#165521 - " *Relativity of simultaneity is a logical consequence of c's invariance. Time order reverseals have not been tested directly as far as I know, but since the invariance of c from which the relativity follows has been tested in a lot of experiments I would say that the thought experiments regarding this issue are solid.* "

Comment: A must read:  "Synchronization Gauges and the Principles of Special Relativity":  http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0409105

Answer (score 2):

The truth of the Lorentz transformation as an accurate description of the co-ordinate transformation between relatively uniformly moving observers *needfully implies* relativity of simultaneity. Contrapositively, the Lorentz transformation *cannot* be sound if simulteneity is not relative. So, in the sense that the soundness of the Lorentz transformation has a great deal of experimental support, there is also strong experimental disproof of the notion of absolute simultaneity. The most in-one's-face results (IMO) are the measurement of varying lifetimes of metastable particles depending on their speed relative to the laboratory; the lengthening of lifetimes is precisely in keeping with the time dilation factor calculated from the Lorentz transformation. See also the Rossi-Hall and Frisch-Smith experiments.

> My intuition tells me that that proving the truth of relative simultaneity compared to absolute simultaneity is impossible, except if time-travel into the past was possible.

Actually it's not anything like as wildly arbitrary as this, and this is one of the most astonishing things about the Lorentz transformation[1]. Whilst the simultaneity of events depends on the observer, the *order* of causally related events is *not* relative. So if a cause comes before an effect in one frame, it does so in all frames. Indeed, this is precisely where the notion of *no signalling faster than lightspeed* comes from: the Lorentz transformation is such that this order preservation is sound as long as we postulate that cause-effect relationships cannot propagate faster than light. In more technical language: the order of *timelike*-separated events *cannot* change under the Lorentz transformations, whereas that of *spacelike* separated events can. So we postulate that cause and effect must define timelike separation: then we recover our altogether everyday experience that causes always come before effects and relativity does not mess with this everyday experience in any way. Notwithstanding time dilation, twin paradoxes and all the rest of it, it's actually quite remarkable how sound our everyday physical intuition remains in a relativistic treatment.

[1]. In this answer I talk wholly about *proper, orthochronous* Lorentz transformations (*i.e.* the identity-connected component of the Lorentz group). These are the transformations comprising rotations, boosts and combinations of these two: to wit: the transformations that can be realized by relative motion. The full Lorentz group includes time reversal and reflexion operators, but these cannot be realized by relative motion.

Answer (score 1):

The relativity of simultaneity is ***not an axiom***, the axiom is that the light velocity is the same in every frame of coordinates. A spot of light travels at the same velocity, *c* with respect to you, and at the same velocity $c$ with respect to a traveler traveling with respect to you at an arbitrary velocity.

So, assume that you send two spots of light to two opposite points, A and B, at the same distance from you, see the figure. According to your clock they reach the points A and B simultaneously.

But consider a traveler in the direction from you to A. She will find, according to her clock, that the spot of light reaches the point A before the other spot reaches B. That happens, in simple words, because the light moves with respect to her at the same velocity, *c*, while the target A *"comes"* toward the traveler while the target B recedes from the traveler. So, the light spot will hit the point A before the other spot hits B.

A traveler in the direction from you to B will find opposite order of hitting the points,ly from symmetrical reasons.

As to experiments of this type, they weren't done so far, but the theory of relativity was tested in different other ways.

[image]

Comment: What puzzles me about this explanation is this...  Cannot the traveler toward A figure out the time taken by the light to travel from A and from B to the traveler (divide the respective distances by the speed of light).  Then, can't the traveler figure out where she was when the light left points A and B (given the two durations and the times when she observed the light) and discover that those events occurred when she was at a single point (and therefore actually were simultaneous)?

Comment: In the frame of coordinates of the traveller, A moves toward the traveller, while B receides. The traveller can send a signal of light to both labs and infer from the Doppler change in the frequency that both labs move with the same absolute velocity, therefore the labs are at rest with respect of one another. But, what information can get the traveller at which times the experiments were done, without landing on the stations of the labs?

Comment: Either you don't understand my question or I don't understand yours.  When the traveler observes the light from A, if the traveler knows A's location and her own location, then she knows the distance between herself and A at that moment.  Given that distance and the speed of light, she knows the duration of time it took for the light to travel from A to her.  If the traveler knows her velocity then she can use that duration to figure out what her location was when the light left A.  Similarly for B, and she'll find the light left A and B when she was at a single point in her travel.

Comment: @Kevin, I think that it's I who does not understand what exactly is the issue that bothers you. I read your question and your comments and it seems to me that you ask a couple of different things. So, let me try to bring order. 1) **was it proven that there is no absolute simultaneity ?** NO!! It was not proven. It's a long talk to explain you the issue. To put it in short, absolute simultaneity means accepting the existece of a preferred frame of coordinates. If there is no preferred frame, the quantum mechanics (QM) leads to a **terrible contradiction**. But, this is matter of advanced QM.

Comment: @Kevin Continuation: Let me though say that the problem of a preferred frame may be totally different at quantum level than in the macroscopic world. 2) In your comment you suggest a procedure for establishing *that those events occurred when she was at a single point (and therefore actually were simultaneous)*. Yes, the traveller may discover that the events occurred simultaneously in some frame. But, does that make the frame preferred? The events may occur on two stations co-moving with the planet Mars. Should this frame be preferred? Why? --- Well, did I help, or did I complicate the issue?

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  It seems it means that from any frame of reference, you would then be able to recognize that the light left A and B at the same time and so it is only the observation of the event that is not absolutely simultaneous, as opposed to the event itself.  Thanks again.

Comment: Dear @Kevin , yes, you understand correctly. Prof. Karl Kassner, a specialist   in the domain, defined the situation as follows: *the event* ( in our case the beam of light from A or from B) *is the same. It's the description of it that changes from frame to frame* (of coordinates). Now, I'll add another example of the strange situations produced when we pass from one intertial frame to another. I am adding now an additional answer. Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in modern physics the idea of absolute simultaneity is definitely shown to be incorrect.

That said, it is possible that some non-physicists use the term absolute simultaneity in a loose way to convey the idea of a universal 'now', which is quite a different question.

It is now well established, by hundreds of experiments, that the speed of light is the same for every inertial observer, and from that it is easy to show that simultaneity is relative. There is a very simple thought experiment you can follow to convince yourself of it.

Suppose I flash a light that heads off in all directions around me. Suppose that there are two detectors equidistant from me, one to the east and one to the west. Let us say they are each 299,792,458 metres away, which is the distance light travels in a second. If I flash the light at exactly 12:00:00, the two detection events will occur at exactly 12:00:01, so I would say they are simultaneous, because the time required for the light to reach one detector is exactly the same as the time required for it to reach the other.

Now imagine that you are walking past me, heading east at a meter per second, at exactly the moment I flash the light. Your watch is synchronised with mine, so we both agree the light was flashed at 12:00:00. As before, the two detection events occur equidistant from me at 12:00:01. However, in your frame, the eastern detector must register the light earlier than the western detector, because in your frame the light has had to travel a metre less in the eastern direction, and a metre more in the western direction. In your frame, therefore, the eastern even occurred fractionally before 12:00:01 while the western event occurred fractionally after 12:00:01, so they were not simultaneous.

Crucially, however, you and I do not disagree about where and when in spacetime the two events occurred- we simply use different coordinate systems to label them. In my coordinate system, the two events have the same t coordinate, while in your coordinate system they don't. There is an objective reality, or an absolute reality if you prefer, about the events having occurred at two specific points in spacetime- they fact that you and I label them differently is in many respects immaterial.

If you are contemplating the philosophy of time, you should bear in mind that simultaneity has a very limited meaning in physics. You might have heard of the Andromeda paradox, which is really just an extension of our thought experiment to massive distances. If you are walking past me, then for you the time on a distance galaxy that is simultaneous with the time on your watch might be several years before or after the time on the galaxy that is simultaneous with the time on my watch, the difference depending on how far away the galaxy is, and the direction in which you are walking.

You might find it helpful to consider the paradox in reverse. Suppose on the distance galaxy there are three people standing together, stationary relative to you, their time synchronised with yours. Now suppose one of the people starts walking away from Earth and one towards it. For the one walking towards you, the simultaneous time on Earth shoots years into the future, while for the one walking away from you, the simultaneous time on earth leaps years back in the past. What difference does that make to the objective reality of 'now' here on Earth? Absolutely none.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking the 'different question' of 'absolute simultaneity', as you phrase it: as "a loose way to convey the idea of a universal 'now'".  This is the concept as addressed in [Thomas Ryckman's 2010 review](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/einstein-relativity-and-absolute-simultaneity/) of *Einstein, Relativity and Absolute Simultaneity*, relatably conveyed therein by astronomer Tom Van Flandern's essay on GPS synchronisation and the Twins' Paradox.  Not, however, unequivocally: the authors have differing ideas of what 'absolute simultaneity' could mean.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen very possibly. And that is the problem with loosely defined ideas- people can argue about them inconclusively until the cows come home.

Comment: It's a moot point because there is no hope for absolute simultaneity with singularities in the picture.  (With no equations for singularities there is no possibility of a compensated timeframe or whatever calculation.  Whether new discoveries could ever improve the matter for absolute simultaneity seems doubtful.). Whether the question still stands for 'regular' spacetime is open.  Closed timelike curves come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Assume two space-stations at rest with respect to one another - therefore their clock-beat is the same. In one station works the experimenter Alice, and in the other station, the experimenter Bob. Consider that at the time $t_0$ by the clock of these stations, each experimenter performs some experiment.

Assume now that the experimenter Charlie is sent to collect the results of the two experiments. Charlie's station is located on the same line as Alice's and Bob's stations, beyond Bob's station:

Charlie_____Bob___________Alice

Charlie decides to start his flight so as to reach Bob's site right in time when Bob does his experiment; immediately after that, Charlie intends to continue to Alice. According to the clock of the ship, Alice performs her experiment before Bob, s.t. when Charlie would be at Alice's station, her result would be ready.

However, after Charlie's ship lands on Bob's station, the beat of the clock of the ship becomes identical to the beat of the clocks of Alice's and Bob's stations. Therefore, Alice appears as performing her measurement again, simultaneously with Bob.

Thus, from the point of view of Charlie, Alice performs her experiment twice. But this is false, Alice performs her experiment only once.

Thus, when passing from one inertial frame to another, the simultaneity changes, and may lead to contradictory descriptions of events.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

The notion of universal, absolute simultaneity is broken by the existence of singularities:

> a condition in which gravity is so intense that spacetime itself
> breaks down catastrophically. As such, a singularity is by definition
> no longer part of the regular spacetime and cannot be determined by
> "where" or "when".

from Wikipedia: [Gravitational singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_singularity#:%7E:text=A%20gravitational%20singularity%2C%20spacetime%20singularity,where%22%20or%20%22when%22.)

[image]

Whether absolute simultaneity is the rule for regular spacetime appears to be elusive to prove, e.g. [Thomas Ryckman's 2010 review](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/einstein-relativity-and-absolute-simultaneity/) of *Einstein, Relativity and Absolute Simultaneity*.

Nevertheless, the OP asks whether it has been "proven that there is no absolute simultaneity?", which is a different matter.

Absolute simultaneity would be beyond observability, and

> An outstanding characteristic of modern physics is the application of
> the principle that only that which is observable is significant.

from Nature 1937 [*Science and the Unobservable*](https://www.nature.com/articles/140963b0).

So defining absolute simultaneity in terms of physics is going to meet challenges, despite conceptualisation in satellite GPS synchronisation.

On the plus side, closed timelike curves that violate causality are theoretical and do not amount to proof or disproof.

e.g. [Closed timelike curves and causality violation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1127) (2010)

Answer (score 0):

> My intuition tells me that that proving the truth of relative simultaneity compared to absolute simultaneity is impossible, except if time-travel into the past was possible.

This is false. You could set up an experiment where you make two flashlights flicker simultaneously in your frame, significantly far apart in space.

Then you could have an observer $A$ in relative motion at speed $v$ with resepect to you detect the light from both flashlights. After $A$ subtracts the light travel time, they will observe a non-zero time-interval between the events.

For a simpler experiment, you could have a third observer $B$ traveling with the same speed $v$ but in the opposite direction. One flashlight is red, and the other is blue. Then $A$ and $B$ will disagree about the **order** that the events "red flicker" and "blue flicker" happened. The time interval between the flickers could even be years depending on $v$, so it would be impossible to account for this using the travel delay of light. If unsatisfied, you could again subtract the light travel times and still see a discrepancy in the **order**